# Creating a variable with get/set inside a module in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a variable with get/set properties inside a module. 
I saw some working examples for creating a get/set property inside a class that looks like this :

```
class MyClass {
    private view;
    get View() { return this.view; }
    set View(value) { this.view = value }
}
```

But I want to do the same inside a module :

```
module MyModule {
    export var view;
    //I want to create get/set methods for view property here
}
```

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's just an oversight; I'll raise this with the design team (I don't see any obvious reason why it would be disallowed other than "we haven't implemented it yet"). It's fairly straightforward to work around lack of first-class language support for it:

```
module Bar {
    var _qua = 42;

    declare export var qua: number;
    Object.defineProperty(Bar, 'qua', {
        get: function() { return _qua; },
        set: function(value) { _qua = value; }
    }); 
}

// Works
var x = Bar.qua;
console.log(x);
Bar.qua = 19;
console.log(Bar.qua);
```

Comment: Still not implemented?

Comment: @ryan-cavanaugh Any update on this feature and if it will ever be implemented?  If not, I would love to hear why!

Answer (score 5):

Accessors are for "members" only. Members can only be part of a class, at least this is how typescript is.

Accessors are defined on the classes prototype, something that a module does not have. If you really want to, you can define it manually, and it does work.

```
module MyModule {
    var view;
    export var View;
    Object.defineProperty(MyModule, "View", {
        get: function () {
            console.log(1);
            return view;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            console.log(2, val);
            view = val;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}

MyModule.View = 555;
window["mm"] = MyModule.View;
```

As expected, I got the output of:

```
> 2 555
> 1
```

Though I honestly would not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap it in a class with static properties:

```
module MyModule {
  export class MyClass {
    private static view;
    static get View() { return this.view; }
    static set View(value) { this.view = value }
  }
}
```