# Returning a function from Javascript into TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have just started out with Typescript and want to convert the following Javascript into Typescript.

The first code block is the actual JS and the second is the TypeScript which I have so far.

I think it's mostly right but the bit I am having trouble working out is the return function at the end of the Javascript. How would I write this bit in my TypeScript code?

```
var ABC = ABC || {};

ABC.navigationService = function () {

var navigate = {};

function navigateChart(e, query) {
}

function drillChart(direction, type, query) {
}

function canDrillUp(series, query) {        
}

function drillUp(series, query) {
}

return {
    navigate: navigateChart,
    drill: drillChart,
    canDrillUp: canDrillUp,
    drillUp: drillUp
}
}

angular.module("MyApp").service("navigationService", [ABC.navigationService]);
```

and with the typescript, this is what I have so far, including only the functions for which I want to return the results as in the Javascript:-

```
module ABC.Visualisation.Services {
'use strict';
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
var canDrilldownPoint = false;
var canDrillupPoint = false;
var canDrilldownSeries = false;
var canDrillupSeries = false;

var navigate = {
    loading: false,
    showGui: false,
    canDrilldownPoint: canDrilldownPoint,
    canDrillupPoint: canDrillupPoint,
    canDrilldownSeries: canDrilldownSeries,
    canDrillupSeries: canDrillupSeries,
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
};

export class NavigationService implements INavigationService {

    public navigateChart(e: any, query: any) {

    }

    public drillChart(direction: string, type: string, query: any): void {
    }


    public canDrillUp(series: any, query: any): boolean {
    }

    public drillUp(series: any, query: any): void {
    }


}
}

angular.module("MyApp").service("NavigationService", [ABC.Visualisation.Services.NavigationService]);
```

Comment: Rather than showing _all_ this code, [could you just include the bits that you're unsure of how to convert from JS to Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - I'm sure most of the variables are unneeded etc, perhaps only one each of the function constructions - they're all just the same thing repeated -  it will help to make your question clearer.

Comment: Ok, i've only put in the code which is in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

1) I believe that

```
angular.module("MyApp").service("NavigationService", [ABC.Visualisation.Services.NavigationService]);
```

should be

```
angular.module("MyApp").service("NavigationService", ABC.Visualisation.Services.NavigationService);
```

2) This is how you can put variables to a module: [Creating a variable with get/set inside a module in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414138/creating-a-variable-with-get-set-inside-a-module-in-typescript)